# pip fails to install pupil-apriltags

Tags: python, pip, apriltags

I keep getting the same message, it says I need to Install Visual Studio but I already have it, (maybe pip doesn't recognize it? or its a bad installation?) I am running on windows have python 3.10, and Visual Studio 2022 community with the python extension.
here is the entire log:

```
× Building wheel for pupil-apriltags (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [50 lines of output]
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
    Generator

      Visual Studio 15 2017

    could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/Jordan/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-bnra7vj7/pupil-apriltags_67071b5788a34192b7169db94dd696e6/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".


  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  ********************************************************************************
  scikit-build could not get a working generator for your system. Aborting build.

  Building windows wheels for Python 3.10 requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2022.
  Get it with "Visual Studio 2017":

    https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

  Or with "Visual Studio 2019":

    https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

  Or with "Visual Studio 2022":

    https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

  ********************************************************************************
  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pupil-apriltags
Failed to build pupil-apriltags
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pupil-apriltags, which is required to install 
pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: you can download it as a file and put it in your python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of digging around, I found that the package is only compatible for python 3.6 and 3.7 not to mention it doesn't work on windows NT or 11... which is really sad in my opinion, apriltags and fiducials in general are growing and for a good reason, why not make the package compatible with 3.10+ (did something change that made it incompatible?) anyway this is me saying to whoever made pupil-apriltags, please fix this!

ps: I did manage to pip install the package in WSL Python 3.7.